# How can I get the rtsp stream from a V380 wifi smart net camera

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I can ping 192.168.15.20 just fine and the camera's online and I can connect to it with the android app I've tried opening `rtsp://admin:password123@192.168.15.20:554/live/ch00_1` and this is the result from my vlc log file:

```
satip debug: try to open 'rtsp://admin:password123@192.168.15.20:554/live/ch00_1'
satip debug: connect to host '192.168.15.20'
main debug: net: connecting to 192.168.15.20 port 554
main error: connection failed: No route to host
satip error: Failed to connect to RTSP server 192.168.15.20:554
main debug: net: connecting to 192.168.15.20 port 554
main error: connection failed: No route to host
access_realrtsp error: cannot connect to 192.168.15.20:554
access_realrtsp debug: could not connect to: 192.168.15.20:554/live/ch00_1
main debug: no access modules matched
main debug: dead input
qt debug: IM: Deleting the input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 1/2)
main debug: nothing to play
```

Comment: Either you don't have a route to `192.168.15.20` or the V380 is off. `ip route` will help with the first.

Comment: Please learn how to use the formatting tools by clicking "help". Questions that are unformatted are hard to read, so fewer of AskUbuntu's volunteers will read them, and you'll get less help.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should Edit your question to add information. By updating your Question, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Install `nmap` and `zenmap`, then portscan the camera.

Comment: you want me to run what nmap or zenmap command and expect what info returned by them?

Comment: I had already assigned the camera a static ip address on my lan so I ran `nmap 192.168.15.20`

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-07-27 21:08 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.15.20
Host is up (0.023s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8800/tcp open  sunwebadmin

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should Edit your question to add information. By updating your Question, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: I have this camera, https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/32795358657.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.2742b90a9oAGjn
Using motion and the instructions:
https://www.unifore.net/ip-video-surveillance/how-to-play-rtsp-video-stream-of-ip-cameras-on-vlc-player-quicktime-player.html
https://bkjaya.wordpress.com/2018/02/02/how-to-use-motion-linux-with-2-web-cams-chinese-ip-camera-on-ubuntu-17-10-artful-aardvark/ This working for me, i created a camera.conf and running a "motion -c camera.conf".
This is a streaming by localhost.
Regards.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you have to activate RTSP in the Cam. Therefore, you have to create a text file with the following content:

```
[CONST_PARAM]
rtsp=1
```

Rename the file to `ceshi.ini`.

Copy it to the root of an empty SD card, put in the cam and repost the cam.

Then you will be able to connect to RSTP over `rtsp://IPADRESS:554/live/ch00_1`.

Comment: Can we connect to the stream without rtsp as v380 pro app use? I can see 2 open ports 8800 and 9800.

Comment: @Nawal doubtful, as it goes thru the internet (yes, camera manufacturers can watch you thru the camera).

Comment: @AgentFire I agree, hard to trust them :| that's why I was looking to get stream locally and keep the camera isolated from internet.

Answer (score 2):

ceshi.ini post works perfectly
just remember to follow bellow steps:

- insert SD card with .ini file
- turn on and wait for 2/3 minutes after boot
- turn off camera
- remove sd card
- turn on again

otherwise it wont work